# MCONCAT for excel 2013 64 bit

Tags: excel

Does anyone know a substitute for MCONCAT for excel 2013 64 bit?

MCONCAT allows to get array of cells and concatenate them with a specified delimiter (instead of typing one by one cells via the concatenate formula). For example: =MCONCAT(A:A,",")

Answer (score 0):

You can write a VBA version or there is a CONCAT.RANGE function in the text functions of FastExcel Speedtools (but its not free: disclaimer - its my product)
http://www.decisionmodels.com/fastexcelV3SpeedTools_Extra.htm